# Remote Host Neighbor Cache Entry State after Neighbor Solicitation request

Tags: ip, ipv6, protocol-theory, ndp

When a Host A sends for the first time a NS request to another Host B, host B answers with a NA.

In Host A Neighbor Cache, the state Entry for host B gets from INCOMPLETE to REACHABLE, when NA comes back.

But what happens in the remote Host B ?
RFC4861 describes :

> Nodes send Neighbor Solicitations to request the link-layer address
>   of a target node while also providing their own link-layer address to
>   the target.

So that means that Host B should take advantage of the situation and make a new entry for Host A in his cache.
But what would the state for this entry be ?

The standard describes:

> Receipt of other Neighbor Discovery messages, such as Router
>   Advertisements and Neighbor Advertisement with the Solicited flag set
>   to zero, MUST NOT be treated as a reachability confirmation. Receipt
>   of unsolicited messages only confirms the one-way path from the
>   sender to the recipient node. In contrast, Neighbor Unreachability
>   Detection requires that a node keep track of the reachability of the
>   forward path to a neighbor from its perspective, not the neighbor’s
>   perspective. Note that receipt of a solicited advertisement
>   indicates that a path is working in both directions. The
>   solicitation must have reached the neighbor, prompting it to generate
>   an advertisement. Likewise, receipt of an advertisement indicates
>   that the path from the sender to the recipient is working. However,
>   the latter fact is known only to the recipient; the advertisement’s
>   sender has no direct way of knowing that the advertisement it sent
>   actually reached a neighbor. From the perspective of Neighbor
>   Unreachability Detection, only the reachability of the forward path
>   is of interest.

So, in our case the Host A shouldn't be declared REACHABLE for Host B ?
Could it be, that it's declared STALE ?

If you could also provide some kind of source document together with your explanation, it would be really appreciated. :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an entry SHOULD be created or updated as STALE, but what a particular OS actually does is off-topic here. *[RFC 4861, Neighbor Discovery for IP version 6 (IPv6)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861)* clearly spells out what happens when Host B receives a Neighbor Solicitation from Host A (*I have highlighted the relevant text*):

> **[7.2.3.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861#section-7.2.3) Receipt of Neighbor Solicitations**
>
> A valid Neighbor Solicitation that does not meet any of the following
> requirements MUST be silently discarded:
>
> - The Target Address is a "valid" unicast or anycast address   assigned to the receiving interface [[ADDRCONF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861#ref-ADDRCONF)],
> - The Target Address is a unicast or anycast address for which the   node is offering proxy service, or
> - The Target Address is a "tentative" address on which Duplicate   Address Detection is being performed [[ADDRCONF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861#ref-ADDRCONF)].
>
> If the Target Address is tentative, the Neighbor Solicitation should
> be processed as described in [[ADDRCONF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861#ref-ADDRCONF)].  Otherwise, the
> following description applies.  ***If the Source Address is not the
> unspecified address and, on link layers that have addresses, the
> solicitation includes a Source Link-Layer Address option, then the
> recipient SHOULD create or update the Neighbor Cache entry for the IP
> Source Address of the solicitation.  If an entry does not already
> exist, the node SHOULD create a new one and set its reachability state
> to STALE as specified in [Section 7.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861#section-7.3.3).  If an entry already
> exists, and the cached link-layer address differs from the one in the
> received Source Link-Layer option, the cached address should be
> replaced by the received address, and the entry's reachability state
> MUST be set to STALE.***
>
> If a Neighbor Cache entry is created, the IsRouter flag SHOULD be set
> to FALSE.  This will be the case even if the Neighbor Solicitation is
> sent by a router since the Neighbor Solicitation messages do not
> contain an indication of whether or not the sender is a router.  In
> the event that the sender is a router, subsequent Neighbor
> Advertisement or Router Advertisement messages will set the correct
> IsRouter value.  If a Neighbor Cache entry already exists, its
> IsRouter flag MUST NOT be modified.
>
> If the Source Address is the unspecified address, the node MUST NOT
> create or update the Neighbor Cache entry.
>
> After any updates to the Neighbor Cache, the node sends a Neighbor
> Advertisement response as described in the next section.

Comment: Nice! But maybe a point stays vague..
Could the the  Neighbor Advertisement response packet that comes after trigger the transition from STALE to DELAY ?