# Can a Neighbor Advertisement response packet trigger the transition from STALE to DELAY?

Tags: ipv6, ndp

I think the title is pretty descriptive.

I cannot seem to find anything in the standard about what kind of packets could trigger the transition from the state STALE to the state DELAY, in the Neighbor Cache Entry.

I site the corresponding text from the RFC4861 standard:

> DELAY: More than ReachableTime milliseconds have elapsed
>   since the last positive confirmation was received that
>   the forward path was functioning properly, and a
>   packet was sent within the last DELAY_FIRST_PROBE_TIME
>   seconds.
>   If no reachability confirmation is received
>   within DELAY_FIRST_PROBE_TIME seconds of entering the
>   DELAY state, send a Neighbor Solicitation and change
>   the state to PROBE.

So, when it says "When a packet is sent...".
**What kind of packets can trigger this transition ?**
Can all possible Packets, even a response to a Neighbor Solicitation, trigger that?

For example:

When a Host A sends for the first time a NS request to another Host B, host B answers with a NA.
In Host A Neighbor Cache, the state Entry for host B gets from INCOMPLETE to REACHABLE, when NA comes back.
And Host B is supposed to add a new entry with Host's A address and in [STALE state](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59911/remote-host-neighbor-cache-entry-state-after-neighbor-solicitation-request).
Could it be, since the entry is in STALE and then a NA packet is sent to Host A, that the Neighbor Cache entry state is updated to DELAY and host B starts sending prob packets after some time ?

Thanks!